# How to find the limit of the following sequence,$2,\cfrac{2}{1+2},\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+2}},\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+2}}},\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the limit of the following sequence $$\left\{2,\cfrac{2}{1+2},\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+2}},\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+2}}},\ldots\right\}$$

I am absolutely clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0=2$, and let your sequence be $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Notice that

$$x_{n+1}=\frac2{1+x_n}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Suppose that the sequence has a limit, say $L$. Then

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{1+x_n}=\frac2{1+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n}=\frac2{1+L}\;.$$

Solve this (and use a little common sense to eliminate the impossible answer), and you’ll know what $L$ has to be if it exists.

If you also have to prove that it converges, you’ll have to work a bit harder.

Comment: how to prove it's convergence?

Comment: how to prove it's convergence?

Comment: @SaurabhRana: Show that if $x_n>1$, then $x_{n+1}<1$, and if $x_n<1$, then $x_{n+1}>1$. Show that $$x_{n+2}-x_n=\frac{(2+x_n)(1-x_n)}{3+x_n}$$ and conclude that $x_{n+2}-x_n$ is negative if $x_n>1$ and positive if $x_n<1$. Use these results to show that $$x_0>x_2>x_4>\ldots>1>\ldots x_5>x_3>x_1\,.$$ The sequence $\langle x_0,x_2,x_4,\ldots\rangle$ is monotone and bounded, so it converges to some limit $L_e$. Express $x_{2(n+1)}$ as a function of $x_{2n}$ and apply the technique that I used in my answer to find $L_e$. You can then either ...

Comment: ... deal similarly with $\langle x_1,x_3,x_5,\ldots\rangle$ or show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x_{2n+1}-x_{2n})=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1}=\frac2{1+a_n}$$

$$a_{\infty}=\frac2{1+a_\infty}$$

$$a_{\infty}=1$$